# Use same QTableView in different tabs

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview

I would like to know if it's possible to use the same **QTableView** in different tabs of a **QTabWidget**. 
For example, when I do:

```
self.table = QTableView()
self.tabs.addTab(self.table, "New Name")
```

it doesn't add a new tab, it simply transforms the title of the current tab to "New Name".

My goal is basically to have a QTableView in each tab, but for a perfs matter, I would like to create only one QTableView object, and simply filter the data for each tab (the raw data are the same for all the tabs). Because you can only have a look to one tab at a time.

Is there an elegant solution ?

Comment: You cannot have the same widget two times as tab in a QTabWidget. Just wrap them in a QWidget and it should work. If the performance is better or worse than having two QTableViews as mentioned by Marcus, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be misinterpreting the function of QTableView; it is meant to be one specific view at a set of data, so exchanging filters when switching tabs is performing worse than having two QTableViews.

The elegant solution you're looking for is thus having two independent QTableViews, not one.

Comment: Yes, exactly: one specific view for a set of data. That's what I have, one set of data, and several tabs displaying the same set of data. However, in each tab, I'll perform a sql query on the model, to display only certain items. That's what I meant by "filtering".

Comment: And that's exactly the role of a View in a Model/View architecture. QTableView is the View that does the filtering.

Comment: Are there any performance measurements how much worse one or the other is? I mean like having two views or having one view and two filters. Both seems possible.

Comment: Not that I'd be aware of. However, please be aware that one is what was intended to be done -- so optimization is likely only to have taken place for that.